Is it possible to approximate a continuous signal using unevenly spaced samples?
I am not well-versed in this topic, so wanted to ask in case there is a well-established answer or method.
The problem can be summarized as follows:
Given a set of points obtained at a variable sampling rate from some sensor, where both the data value and the timestamp of when it was sampled are available, is it possible to reconstruct or approximate a corresponding fixed sampling rate signal?
Alternatively, is it possible to accurately calculate peak per minute value for this random-sampling signal ?

The answer is yes. See here for more details: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~strohmer/research/sampling/irsampl.html

Dan's comment not withstanding: this depends a LOT on the details, i.e. what are the statistics of the sampling process and what is the frequency content of the signal.

Here's a related question and answer. On another note, a simple and common way to deal with non-uniform sampling is to resample it (interpolate) to a uniform sampling. This reconstruction is not perfect, but depending on the interpolation method and application it is often good enough.

@Gillespie what are some known algorithms for interpolating to a uniform sampling?
